# Firebase.set() adds extra nodes

Tags: javascript, firebase

When running the following query using the root directory of my Firebase, extra nodes are added.

Query:

```
fire.set({
"users":[
    {
        "0":[
            {
                "email":"foobar@gmail.com",
                "snake":[
                    {
                        "highScore":"15"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
});
```

Result

[image: Malformed entry.]

I get the same result when formatting the data in a json file and importing it directly using the Firebase web interface. Did I miss something in the documentation perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that any time you use array syntax, i.e. [ ... ], you're creating an "array" in Firebase, which we do by just creating an object with numeric keys (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...).

So if you do:

```
ref.set({ a: 5 });
```

The resulting object will be:

```
{ a: 5 }
```

But if you instead do:

```
ref.set([{a: 5}, {b: 6}]);
```

You'll get:

```
{ 
  '0': { a: 5 }, 
  '1': { b: 6 } 
}
```

So if you just remove the square brackets from the data you're setting, e.g.:

```
fire.set({
  "users": {
    "0": {
      "email":"foobar@gmail.com",
      "snake": {
        "highScore":"15"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The resulting data in the web interface should match your data exactly.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks very much for the clear explanation. Is this properly explained somewhere in the docs?

Comment: I could have sworn we talk about array handling somewhere, but now I can't find it, so maybe not!  I'll see if we can get it added.